# Xcode Code Extension was working now it’s gone gray

Tags: xcode-extension, xcode8

This is very frustrating. I finally managed to get my Xcode Source Code extension working in Xcode (not the debugger).

I’ve been happy for a week.

I found a couple of bugs. I fixed the first one and everything continued to work. When I fixed the second bug, Xcode grayed out my extension.

Rebooting didn’t fix it. Xcode-select didn’t fix it. Oh, and now the Apple’s “comment selection” is grayed out as well.

Does **anyone** have a good solution to assure this works?